# Django caused Unable to connect with Docker

Tags: docker, django

I found a Django project and failed to get it running in Docker container in the following way:

1. `git clone https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast.git`
2. `$ cat requirements.txt`

   #psycopg2==2.6.0  # if use postgreSQL as DB backend

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Next, I ran:

```
$ docker run --name some-django-app -p 8000:8000 -d my-django-app
4202d7b2b47603e32dc800d3fbedbfaf4363f8cafe45684242aa3bb2b0eba257
```

Finally, I typed `http://localhost:8000/` and got `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000`.

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your requirements.txt, change kombo version to 3.0.30. This will solve the first error:

I've just reproduced your steps. By doing **docker logs some-django-app** I've seen this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute

    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/src/app/i5k/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/usr/src/app/i5k/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from celery import five
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/five.py", line 149, in <module>
    from kombu.utils.compat import OrderedDict  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from uuid import UUID, uuid4 as _uuid4, _uuid_generate_random
ImportError: cannot import name _uuid_generate_random
```

And it seems to be exactly [this issue](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/545).

As you fix the kombo version, a new error will appear (checked by using docker logs):

```
 [root@:/.../django-blast]# docker logs test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/apps.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .signals import register_hstore_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    from psycopg2 import ProgrammingError
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

And it seems that the package you don't want to use is needed...

```
# grep -ir psycopg2
webapollo/models.py:import psycopg2
webapollo/models.py:            conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=' + self.db_name + ' user=' + self.db_acct + ' host=' + self.host)
webapollo/models.py:        conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=' + species.db_name + ' user=' + species.db_acct + ' host=' + species.host)
webapollo/models.py:        conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=' + species.db_name + ' user=' + species.db_acct + ' host=' + species.host)
i5k/settings_prod.py:    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
i5k/settings.py:    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

You can keep working at this way or just do a full migration to newer python versions.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the easiest way to PostgreSQL?