# Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '11.7'

Tags: postgresql, python, django, docker-compose

I found a Django project and failed to get it running in Docker container in the following way:

1. `git clone https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast.git`

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

For `docker-compose.yml` I use:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Next, I ran into this error:

```
$ docker-compose build
...
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-Gq_JSR/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '11.7'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '11.7'

Known [bug](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/598) for `psycopg2<=2.6.2`. Try upgrading by editing its [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast/blob/master/requirements.txt#L18) and changing `psycopg2==2.6.0` to `psycopg2==2.7`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, after `docker-compose up` I got `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000`. What did I miss?

Comment: did you deploy the compose file and run Firefox at the same machine?

Comment: Yes, I did. After, I posted I forgotten to change `kombo` to 3.0.30 in `requirements.txt ` ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/1063515/367023)). Unfortunately, I got a new error `ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference`. What did I miss?

Comment: Try using latest `psycopg2`, `psycopg2==2.8.6` in your `requirements.txt`, and try running it again.

Comment: Thank you, this fix it, but I got a new error: ```web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |  Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
web_1  |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```. What did I miss?